# Double integral over unit square

Tags: definite-integrals, multiple-integral

I'm trying to calculate a closed form of this double integral

$$\int_0^1\int_0^1(1-y)^a\,x^{b\,y-1}(x-1/2)^n\,dx\,dy \tag{1}$$

with $a>-1$, $b>0$ and $n=0,1,2,\dots$

If we apply the Newton binomial to $(z-1/2)^n$ our problem reduces to calculate integrals of the form

$$\int_0^1\int_0^1(1-y)^a\,x^{b\,y-1+n}\,dx\,dy$$

Those integrals are easy to calculate except the case $n=0$, that is,

$$\int_0^1\int_0^1(1-y)^a\,x^{b\,y-1}\,dx\,dy$$

I've checked $(1)$ with Wolfram and it seems to be finite. I've also checked in several books of definite integrals but I've had no luck.

Any help will be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I get
$$\begin{align}\int_0^1\int_0^1(1-y)^ax^{by-1}dx\,dy&=\int_0^1(1-y)^a\left.\frac{x^{by}}{by}\right|_0^1dy=\int_0^1\frac{(1-y)^a}{by}dy\\
&>\int_0^{1/2}\frac{dy}{2^aby}=\left.\frac{\ln y}{2^ab}\right|_0^{1/2}=\infty\end{align}$$
Indeed [WA agrees with one sample integral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E1%28int_0%5E1%28%281-y%29%5E%281%2F2%29x%5E%28y%2F2-1%29%29dx%29dy).